# How do I update my servers' domain name for Reverse DNS?

Tags: debian, domain-name, reverse-dns

I'm updating my mail servers' rDNS and I think I have it all figured out except for one thing.

When I installed my OS (Debian Etch), the installer asked me to enter the "domain name".

1. Is the "domain name" updated by using the `hostname` command?
2. If so, which config file(s) are updated when using the `hostname` command?
3. If not, how do I change my servers' domain name?

My current /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
67.228.178.164  mrspock.example-old.com      mrspock
```

My current /etc/hostname:

```
mrspock
```

$ hostname -f

```
mrspock.example-old.com
```

I need to update `hostname -f` to be `mrspock.example-new.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It appears (according to [this](http://debian-resources.org/node/125/) and [this](http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/ChangeHostname)) that you only need to update /etc/hosts to change the domain name specified during install on a Debian system:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
67.228.178.164  mrspock.example-new.com      mrspock
```

That should do it. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't find any other info on changing the domain name. Also, `hostname -f` produces "mrspock.example-new.com" after updating /etc/hosts, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the "domain name" updated by using the hostname command?
>
> If so, which config file(s) are updated when using the hostname command?

No! hostname Command update /etc/hostname

> how do I change my servers' domain name?

you can change your domainname by:

```
# domainname <NEWNAME>
```